# Update/Refresh TextBlock which is bind to another element property in wpf/xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, textblock

I would like to update text in textblock which is bind to listview item property. This is the way i bind textblock to listview item.

**mWindow.xaml**

```
<ListView Name="ListViewDetails"               
      ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" 
      SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPerson}">
      ...
</ListView> 

<TextBlock>
     <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=ListViewDetails, Path=SelectedItem.Office}"/>
     ...
</TextBlock>
```

If item property in listview is changed, text isn't updated.

**mWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class mWindow: Window , INotifyPropertyChanged 
{

            private Person currentPerson;
            public Person CurrentPerson
            {
                get
                {
                    return currentPerson;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.currentPerson = value;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentPerson"); 
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }

            }

            private void editLisView{

            ...

            // refresh ListView
            ICollectionView view =CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ListViewInsuranceDetails.ItemsSource);
            view.Refresh();
            }

}
```

Comment: Does the bound item implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Check your output window if binding is not breaking!!

Comment: @Charleh Yes I did, but I don't know, if my solution is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I had to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for CurrentPerson property. When I implement INotifyPropertyChanged for person class, it works.